# Target function of Gradient Descent in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

When using a neural network to construct a classifier ,I used the GD,but it seems I didn't understand it well. what's the difference between the two implements of target function about Gradient Descent where D is a classifier while X is labeled 1  and Y is labeled 0.

example 1:

```
n_true = classifier(X) 
n_false = classifier(Y)
loss = 0.5 * (tf.reduce_mean((n_true - 1)**2) + tf.reduce_mean(n_false**2))
solver = (tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss))
```

example 2:

```
results  = tf.concat([n_true, n_false], 0)
lables = np.transpose(np.hstack((np.ones(size),np.zeros(size))))
loss = 0.5 * (tf.reduce_mean(results-lables)**2)
solver = (tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss))
```